# What is the way to use 2 arrays in a listview.builder in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I have 2 arrays and I want to put them in one `Listview.builder` so that they scroll together. (The first array item appears and when you scroll more you arrive to the second array), each one should have a header before its items.
I tried to put them in 2 listviews but the screen got divided and the scene was horrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested using  `ListView.builder`

```dart
class ListTest2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const ListTest2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final list1 = List.generate(4, (i) => "list1 i $i");
    final list2 = List.generate(4, (i) => "list2 i $i");

    final combineList = [...list1, ...list2];
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: combineList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            if (index == 0 && list1.isNotEmpty) {
              return Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text("header of List 1"),
                  Text(combineList[index]),
                ],
              );
            }

            if (index == list1.length && list2.isNotEmpty) {
              return Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text("header of List 2"),
                  Text(combineList[index]),
                ],
              );
            }

            return Text(combineList[index]);
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Or You can do it like

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: ListView(
    children: [
      Text("List1 header  "),
      ...list1.map((e) => Text(e)),
      Text("List2 header "),
      ...list2.map((e) => Text(e)),
    ],
  ),
);
```

If you like to ignore header on empty case,

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final list1 = List.generate(4, (i) => "list1 i $i");
  final list2 = List.generate(4, (i) => "list2 i $i");

  return Scaffold(
    body: ListView(
      children: [
        if (list1.isNotEmpty) Text("List1 header  "),
        ...list1.map((e) => Text(e)),
        if (list2.isNotEmpty) Text("List2 header "),
        ...list2.map((e) => Text(e)),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: How can i do it in the listview.builder ? because i use the builder to have an index and specify the maximum items to appear because my list is huge.

Comment: You can create sublist like `...list2.sublist(0, list2.length > 4 ? 4 : list2.length) .map((e) => Text(e)),` where it is allowed to have maximum 4 item on list2, Does it work on your case?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the arrays into a single array before passing to the `ListView`'s `children`:

```dart
ListView(
    ...
    children: <Widget>[
        Text("array1 header"),
        ...array1,
        Text("array2 header"),
        ...array2,
    ],
    ...
)
```